# Instantiate template function depending on assignment

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function that returns a random number and is templated against ints and floats with concepts.

```
template <typename T>
struct distribution_selector;

template<std::integral I>
struct distribution_selector<I> {
    using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<I>;
};

template<std::floating_point F>
struct distribution_selector<F> {
    using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<F>;
};

struct random {
    std::mt19937 engine;
};

template<typename T>
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
constexpr inline decltype(auto) rand(random& r, T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) {
    using distribution = distribution_selector<T>::type;
    return distribution(min, max)(r.engine);

}
```

for ease of use, i want to omit the template argument for `T` depending on what I assign the result of the function to:

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace r;
    random r;
    int i = rand(r,0,2); // will call rand<int>, correct
    short s = rand(r,0,3); // will call rand<int>, but I want rand<short>
    double d = rand(r,0,6); // will also call rand<int>, but i want rand<double>
    double dd = rand<double>(r,0,6); // will of course call rand<double>
    return s;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x3n6G8EYh)

Is that possible?

Comment: Indirectly yes, but it comes with several caveats, specifically if there is no (unique) type to convert to, e.g. in `auto x = ...` or in function overload resolution with multiple choices. Why is the current syntax a problem? The user has to specify the type somewhere anyway and they only need to do so once: `auto i = rand<int>(r,0,2);`. Deduction from the second and third argument will also work if done properly: `auto i = rand(r,0,2); auto s = rand(r, short(0), short(3));` and so on. (The third parameter could also be modified so that `auto i = rand(r,short(0),3)` will work)

Comment: you can deduce `T` from the min and max passed to the funciton

Comment: It's not really a "problem", but cumbersome to always write the type when the type is known already (what i want to assign to).
And `short s = rand<short>(r)` and `auto s = rand<short>(r)` aswell as `auto s = rand(r,(short)0,1)` look stupid in my eyes

Comment: it is possible, but the only way I know how to get there requires the types of the arguments to be known before you can deduce the return type (and then you can deduce the type from `int a =`)

Comment: Well, if you really want to try it, the trick is to have a `rand` which doesn't actually call the random number generator or determine `T`,  but only returns a proxy object storing the function arguments and with a template conversion function which then actually calls the random number generator. The conversion function template's template parameter will be deduced to the type you want (with a lot of caveats). It is also a dangerous approach because you have to make sure that the user wont store the proxy object, which can be done only partially. I don't have time to write it up right now.

Comment: you can do something like this https://godbolt.org/z/5of3P1GGM. Though it requires two steps: 1 call the function, `T` is not known yet, 2 convert the proxy to `T`. I dont see how this helps in your case, because you need `T` already for the type of the arguments

Comment: @user17732522 Imho the caveats arent that bad, and can be mitigated to some degree. The bigger issue I see is that to return the proxy `T` must already be known, because its the type of the functions arguments

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't think this solution addresses the OP problem - he needs arguments types of the function to be deduced from return type. Return type conversion happens anyway and not a problem here

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Let `rand` take the arguments by forwarding reference irregardless of type. Store them by-reference in the proxy, then do conversion and concept check inside the conversion function template. It will mess with SFINAE if there are checks for whether a given call to `rand` is allowed, but not if the check also tests that `rand` returns the correct type as usually is the case for concept checks.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind what I said. `T` is type of the arguments of the function, hence returning a proxy does not really help to defer deduction of `T`.

Comment: @user17732522 that would work :) But really not sure if the added complexity is worth it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry, missed this part.

Comment: @user17732522 actually this approach would justify a reopen if someone writes it up in an answer, though atm I cannot do it

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not Haskell, C++ cannot infer types of expressions based on the surrounding context.

What you can do though is infer the type of variable based on the initialization (it's not an assignment):

```
auto i = rand<int>(r,0,2);  // int i
auto s = rand<short>(r,0,3); // short s
auto d = rand<double>(r,0,6); // double d
auto dd = rand<double>(r,0,6); // double dd
```

Provided that `rand` returns the correct type.